# Prevent mass assignment in Idiorm and Paris ORM

Tags: php, mass-assignment, idiorm

My ORM - Paris and Idiorm - doesn't seem to support white-listing parameters passed to constructor function, coming from client side.

```
$fruit = Model::factory('Fruit')->create($_POST);
```

If I want the users to be able to choose only some parameters, like color, and not others, like price, how do I do this? `$_POST` must be somehow filtered. I cannot find anything in Idiorm's/Paris's docs or source.

Comment: I am reminded by an upvote that I offered some assistance to you last year. Did this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$fruit = Model::factory('Fruit')->create(
    array_intersect_key($_POST, array('color' => 1,))
);
```

The function `array_intersect_key` will return key-value pairs where the key appears in both arrays, and the value will be taken from the first array - so the `$_POST` must come first.

You can add new key values in the second parameter - and the values for those keys can be anything.

Comment: I wanted something more beautiful built-in Paris itself, but since there isn't such a thing I'm accepting your answer